# is there a way to add lot sizes to buildings and houses in react-map-gl as in the image below

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl

[image: image1]

I need to show the sizes of the properties in the map.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Mapbox GL JS, you can retrieve the GeoJSON features of the rendered buildings using [`Map#queryRenderedFeatures`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#queryrenderedfeatures) and pass the resulting features to [Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/)'s [`area` method](https://turfjs.org/docs/#area) to compute the areas of these polygons in square meters.

Once you have these numeric values, you can compute the visual "center" of each polygon with Turf's [`centroid` method](https://turfjs.org/docs/#centroid) and use these coordinates to add a [symbol layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#symbol) displaying the area for each polygon at its respective coordinates.